# Include Intel-compiler variables into CMake makefile

Tags: macos, cmake, environment-variables, eclipse-cdt

I'm using CMake 2.8.6 and the latest *Intel C++ Compiler* for a program which is compiled for Linux, MacOSX and Windows. For the development I'm using Eclipse with CDT on Linux and MacOSX.

Until recently I used CMake to create usual Makefiles which I ran from the console. To have a working environment, the Intel compiler comes with a shell-script called `iccvars.sh` which can be `source`d to set all required include- and library-paths.

Now I decided to give the Eclipse-CDT build-system a chance and used the "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" generator of CMake to create an Eclipse project file. Everything works fine under Linux, but under OSX, Eclipse does not know about the environment variables and therefore paths like `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` are missing and the compilation stops because libraries are not found.

**Update**

Let me explain in more detail what I do. I'm running

```
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" path/to/src
```

from within the terminal where `source iccvars.sh` was executed and all environment-variables are set correctly. If I would have created a normal Makefile there and would run `make`, the compilation would succeed. This is because of the `DYLIB_LIBRARY_PATH` (in Linux `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) is set correctly and I do not have to give `-L/path/to/libs` as option to the compiler.

But instead, I start Eclipse and import the created `.project` which works fine. The problem is that Eclipse do not know about my environment in the console and therefore cannot find the required libraries. One solution would be to use `find_library` inside `CMakeLists.txt` and locate every required library because then the full path should be included in the created Makefiles. Instead, I was wondering whether...

**Question:** Is there a way to *source the `iccvars.sh` into my CMakeLists.txt* so that the paths are available even when I'm not in my usual terminal-environment? Are there other possibilities?

**Please note**, that I know you can set environment variables for GUI-programs under OSX. What you have to do is to create a file `environment.plist` in your home under `~/.MacOSX`. In this xml-file you put all your variables a GUI program should have. This works fine for other applications, but especially the Eclipse-builder seems to ignore this.

Comment: If that `iccvars.sh` script only sets environment, you can try to generate CDT projects right after running it: `iccvars.sh && cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 or whatever" project/dir`. If this works, wouldn't need to run it each time before compilation.

Comment: @arrowdodger Yes, that's what I'm doing. I run cmake in the correct environment. Please see my update in the post.